# Are there alternatives to begin/end with stricter scope?

Tags: crystal-lang

In Crystal, are there any alternatives to the following, but without creating the value of `b` after the `end`?

```
  my_val = begin
    a = 1
    b = 2
    a + b
  end
  b should be undefined here.
```

I release it's possible to use `-> {}.call` (but this creates an unneeded closure). There's also `1.times { ... }`, but this seems hacky.  Is there a shortcut to this within the language itself that is idiomatic?

Comment: Could you give some example code as to where this would be useful? Typically I'd say this is a very good sign that you want to refactor out your code into a method.

Comment: @RX14 Thanks. You answered the 1st question: Crystal doesn't have it. The other question: Would Crystal need this? Probably not.  I don't have any compelling use case at this moment to justify advocating it to other people.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this, though I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your particular case the following could be not idiomatic, but depending on what you want to achieve this can be good to be aware of:

### Macro

```
myval = {% begin %}
  a = 1
  b = 2
  a + b
{% end %}

myval #=> 3
b     #=> undefined local variable or method 'b' (did you mean 'p'?)
```

### Method

```
def myval
  a = 1
  b = 2
  a + b
end

myval #=> 3
b     #=> undefined local variable or method 'b' (did you mean 'p'?)
```

### Block

```
myval = :any.try do
  a = 1
  b = 2
  a + b
end

myval #=> 3
b     #=> undefined local variable or method 'b' (did you mean 'p'?)
```

Comment: How did you first learn about `{% begin %}{% end %}`? I never encountered that before in the Crystal docs I've read.

Comment: There are a lot of undocumented stuff as the language is not released. `{% begin %}{% end %}` is similar to macro conditionals documented [here](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/macros.html). Just keep playing with it :D